# What is the geometrical representation of |z-a|-|z+a|=2c?

Tags: complex-analysis

I stumbled across the following question-

What is the geometrical representation of $|z-a|-|z+a|=2c $ where $c$ is a Real number for the following cases - $(I)$ $c>|a|$ and $(II)$ $c=a$.

I tried to put $z=x+iy$ and try to square and expand ,but it didn't work out. Can anyone elegantly find out the geometrical representation for the above 2 cases ?

Comment: You can read it out of the equation. $|z-a|$ and $|z+a|$ are the distances from $z$ to the fixed points $a,-a$. The points $z$ satisfying the equation are those for which the difference between their distances to two fixed points is a constant $2c$. That's a [hyperbola](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbola#As_locus_of_points) with foci at $a,-a$.

Comment: @NDB more precisely, it's one branch of hyperbola since left hand side changes signs depending on whether we are closer to $a$ or $-a$.

Comment: These comments should be an answer.

Comment: Raghav, if you write in your post more context, your efforts and attempts, I will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
Put Just not only $$z=x+ iy$$ and also $$a=a_1 +ia_2$$

Answer (score 0):

HINT: For two fixed point $F$ and $F'$, the locus of point $P$ described by the equation $PF-PF'=constant$ is a hyperbola. In complex plane, $|z_1-z_2|$ represents the distance between points $z_1$ and $z_2$ so $|z-1|$ and $|z-(-1)|$ are essentially $PF$and $PF'$.The use of inequalities like $<$ and $>$ describe the regions containing or excluding the origin .